# How to keep my flutter app running in the background when close?

Tags: android, flutter

I am building an app and I want it to show up in the user's notification bar and run in the background even when it's closed. Similar to "KWGT Kustom Widget Maker".

I've tried looking for libraries that allow this, but I can only find those related to java. Are there any available for Dart/Flutter or any other workaround? I am only targeting android devices.

Answer (score 2):

The mechanism for this feature involves setting up an isolate. Isolates are Dart’s model for multithreading, though an isolate differs from a conventional thread in that it doesn’t share memory with the main program. You’ll set up your isolate for background execution using callbacks and a callback dispatcher.

For more information and a geofencing example that uses background execution of Dart code, see [Executing Dart in the Background with Flutter Plugins and Geofencing](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124), an article in the Flutter Publication on Medium. At the end of this article, you’ll find links to example code, and relevant documentation for Dart, iOS, and Android

Answer (score 2):

I used a package called [flutter_background](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background) , which worked for me perfectly.

Comment: only android compatible

Answer (score 1):

After searching, I guess you have two solution:

You can use flutter wrapper for both android and IOS platform, but you won't be able to run jobs often than every 15 minutes. If you want to schedule jobs more often, you'll need to write platform dependent code, using the `android_alarm_manager` flutter package and `background_fetch` for IOS.
You can trigger the correct one using the `Platform` function in dart.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Isolates for this, also you can use android_alarm_manager or background_fetch libraries

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [flutter_workmanager](https://github.com/vrtdev/flutter_workmanager) plugin.
It's better than the `android_alarm_manager` plugin since it uses newer API's on Android and also works with iOS.

Comment: but one off task not available in ios.

Comment: workmanager can only print mesages, it cannot use any function or methodcall. Pathetic

Comment: android_alarm_manager can run the task periodically in seconds - whereas flutter_workmanager can achieve min 15 min timeframe. android_alarm_manager is clearly a winner.

Comment: android_alarm_manager and workmanager. Between these which is able to run tasks even when the app is closed from the ram/recent apps?

Comment: Work_manager can't be used if it is needed less than 15 minutes. It schedules more than 15 minutes